# Using delta Method

Tags: probability

I'm showing that if $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overset{i.i.d}{\sim}U[0,a]$ for $a>0$, then 
$$
\sqrt{n}(\log(2 \overline{X}_n)-\log a)\xrightarrow[d]{n \to \infty} N(0,1/3).
$$
For the mean and variance I got:
$$
EX_1=\frac{a}{2}, \quad \quad \sigma_{X_1}^2=\frac{a^2}{12}.
$$
I think I've solved as:
$$
2\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}_n-a/2)\xrightarrow[d]{n \to \infty}  N(0, 4\sigma^2)\quad \quad \textrm{by CLT}.
$$
It turns out when I use the delta method: set $g(w)=\log w$

$$
\sqrt{n}(\log(\overline{X}_n)-\log (a/2)) \xrightarrow[d]{n \to \infty}N\left( 0,\frac{a^2}{12}[g'(a)]^2\right)=N\left( 0,\frac{4a^2}{12}\frac{1}{a^2}\right)=N\left(0,\frac{1}{3} \right).
$$

Comment: I don't understand your question. You get the right answer it seems via your computation on the last line. What is the issue with the asymptotic distribution you found for $\bar X_n$... what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: I edited it. I figured out what was wrong. I was suffering with the constant 2, however I realized one can play with it. Thanks for your answer, sorry If I made this confusing.